# Tree view columns for journal items in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I want to write a custom module that adjusts which columns are visible when you search for journal items in OpenERP 6.1. Unfortunately, the columns displayed don't match the columns in the view definitions. Where are the columns really defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tracing through the code, I found that `account_move_line` overrides `fields_view_get` and either replaces or heavily modifies the list of columns. It seems to make its decision based on the journal views that are configured under Accounting: Configuration: Financial Accounting: Journals: Journal Views. If you change a journal's view, or edit one of the journal views, you can change which fields appear in the journal items tree view.

Of course, I could also have read the [documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/book/3/3_9/journals.html).